# grouping of array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an numbered array like this in PHP

Original array:

```
Array
        (
            [i] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [qty] => 5
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [qty] => 5
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [qty] => 5
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [qty] => 5
                        )
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [qty] => 5
                        )    
                )

        )
```

I want it to group the same "id" and add up quantity if there are duplicates, If the "id" is the key instead of numbered keys, I should be able to do it.

What I expected the results is:

```
Array
        (
            [i] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [qty] => 10
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [qty] => 10
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [qty] => 5
                        )    
                )

        )
```

Comment: The idea of SO is that you try and write some code, if it does not work you ask for some help. **But we do not write your code for you from a spec**

Comment: do you want to group only the 2nd level ?

Comment: 4 Upvotes on this question ___Really! who are you people!___ I know its the season of good will to all men ___BUT!___

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Solution

```
<?php 
$your_arr = array(
    array('id' => 1,'qty' => 5),
    array('id' => 2,'qty' => 5),
    array('id' => 2222,'qty' => 5),
    array('id' => 1,'qty' => 5),
    array('id' => 3,'qty' => 5)
);
$new = array();
foreach ($your_array as $r){
    if(!isset($new[$r['id']]))$t=0; //check the current id exist in $new if Not $t = 0; 
    else $t=$r['qty']; //if yes $t's value become the saved value in $new[$r['id']]
    $new[$r['id']]['id'] = $r['id'];
    $new[$r['id']]['qty'] = ($t+$r['qty']); // add the new value with $new[$r['id]]'s value.

}
echo "<pre>";print_r($new);
?>
```

Comment: This works for me, but i will reindex the array by $reindexed = array_values($new);

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that there is another way except of writing your own method processing the original array creating your target array. Something like this:

```
private function processArray($original) {
    $target = array();

    foreach ($original as $originalEntry) {
        foreach ($target as $targetEntry) {
            if ($targetEntry['id'] === $originalEntry['id']) {
                $targetEntry['qty'] = $targetEntry['qty'] + $originalEntry['qty'];
                continue 2;
            }
        }
        $target[] = $originalEntry;
    }
    return $target;
}
```

I haven't had time to test this method but it should concatenate all entries with the same `id` adding up all `qty` fields.